# hide Split view only in one particular View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have one SplitView controller which i have set in Application Delegate class.
Now I want to do that I want to hide Split view only in one particular view controller other wise it will be shown.
I know the method to hide split view but it will be hidden or shown in all the view controller how can i do that for particular one view Controller.

-Thanx in advance

Comment: just add this [[UISplitViewController appearance] setHidden:YES]; in the view which you want to hide it and keep it in mind that this will work only for IOS 5

Comment: @SreeCharan it's get crashing on that line

Comment: can you post some code, how are you adding split view controller in your delegate

Comment: i have added it from xib and in delegate jst write that:[window addSubview:splitViewController.view]

Comment: ok, if you have added it from xib, you should have given IBOutlet, right? so, give that ouletname.hidden = YES; then

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10268/discussion-between-aakil-ladhani-and-sree-charan)